# Java Spring AutoWire byName

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, autowired

I'm currently doing novice tutorial about Spring, it seems i have everything the same like person who makes this tutorial but i keep getting errors `NullPointerException` , could someone help me?

There is section in my xml that is commented if you uncomment it, program will work. But without it, when I try to use autowire byName it doesn't work.

Main Class:

```
public class MainSpring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("konfiguracja.xml");
    SomeBean bean = context.getBean("SomeBean",SomeBean.class);

    System.out.println(bean.getInjectedBean1().getName());
    System.out.println(bean.getInjectedBean2().getName()); 
    }
}
```

InjectedBean Class

```
package springTutorial;

public class InjectedBean {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

SomeBean Class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class SomeBean {

    private InjectedBean InjectedBean1;
    private InjectedBean InjectedBean2;
    public InjectedBean getInjectedBean1() {
        return InjectedBean1;
    }
    public void setInjectedBean1(InjectedBean injectedBean1) {
        this.InjectedBean1 = injectedBean1;
    }
    public InjectedBean getInjectedBean2() {
        return InjectedBean2;
    }
    public void setInjectedBean2(InjectedBean injectedBean2) {
        this.InjectedBean2 = injectedBean2;
    }



}
```

Configuration.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">


    <bean id="InjectedBean1" class="springTutorial.InjectedBean" >

    <property name="name" value="asasa" >


    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="InjectedBean2" class="springTutorial.InjectedBean" >

    <property name="name" value="vbvb">

    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean  id="SomeBean" class="springTutorial.SomeBean" autowire="byName" >

<!--    <property name="injectedBean1"> -->

<!--    <ref bean="InjectedBean1"/> -->

<!--    </property> -->


<!--    <property name="injectedBean2"> -->

<!--    <ref bean="InjectedBean2"/> -->
<!--    </property> -->

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Change your bean ids to `injectedBean1` and `injectedBean2`, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indicate where you get the error when running under the IDE.

Comment: It works, thank you for help and i wish you good day :)

Comment: @Ravencrest1985: you too. I hope you now understand what was the problem :-).

Answer (score 0):

As per Configuration.xml ; InjectedBean1,InjectedBean2 are not injected with any values.

So basically InjectedBean1 and InjectedBean2  are null.

On null you are trying for get Operation which is leading to null pointer exception.

Adding ref to InjectedBean1 and InjectedBean2  will solve problem.

```
<bean id="SomeBean" class="com.stackoverflow.SomeBean" autowire="byName">
        <property name="injectedBean1">
            <ref bean="inject1" />
        </property>
        <property name="injectedBean2">
            <ref bean="inject2" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: inject1 and inject2 need to be defined.I havent included here.